# How to get all user's likes using facebook's graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I query facebook's graph API to retrieve all user's likes (not only pages but also photos and others)?

For instance, how could I get all the pictures a user has liked? Using facebook's search bar you can find them easily by clicking on "photos  has liked".

I wrote a script that scrapes the page content and does that but it's not very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't to my knowledge any way to get this from the API without grabbing every type of response from the API and then sorting through for likes. Facebook search bar uses an internal API different from the Graph API.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently come accross a similar problem, maybe this helps you solve it.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{page_id}/feed?fields=likes.limit(1).summary(true)&since={start_date}&until={end_date}&access_token={access_token}
```

This will give you a list of all posts that received likes during the specified time period. If you manage to write a code summing up the following JSON path you got your sum for "**all user's likes**":

```
data[0].likes.summary.total_count
```

Not entirely sure is this is exactly what you were searching for, hope it helps you though - and if not you, someone else.

As for **likes** you can also use the same way to extract Shares and Comments:
**Shares**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{page_id}/feed?fields=shares&since={start_date}&until={end_date}&access_token=
```

**Comments**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{page_id}/feed?fields=comments.limit(1).summary(true)&since={start_date}&until={end_date}&access_token=
```

Best regards

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. It is indeed very useful!